# Spring boot app does not see configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-configuration

I'm a newcamer in Spring Boot. And I feel like I have some configuration issue.

I want to create file `business-config.yml` with data for business validation. But Spring does not see this file, wherever I put it. And there's no any exception or error. The application successfully reads the files `application.yml` and `bootstrap.yml` and I see all the values from them in the actuator. But there're no values from any new files `business-config.yml` in the actuator. How can I point it correctly to set it properly?
[image]

And why do these files `application.yml` and `bootstrap.yml` have such green icons in the form of a spring icon? How can this be setted? Where do you need to specify and register these files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Spring that it must also check for other files in addition to the defaults. You can do this with the following property:

```
spring.config.additional-location = classpath:/business-config.yml
```

or `spring.config.import` if you are using Spring Boot 2.4 or above:

```
spring.config.import = business-config.yml
```

Regarding "And why do these files application.yml and bootstrap.yml have such green icons in the form of a spring icon?" the answer is that those are the standard Spring-Boot configuration files that IntelliJ is able to identify as Spring related and thus the icon.

Comment: @Michael, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.